# Bazel linker not finding function defines

Tags: c++, bazel

I've been able to make a fair amount of progress in trying to add Bazel build files to enable the building of the gennorm2 tool in ICU. Here is [my work-in-progress PR](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/pull/1524/files) using the Bazel target `//icu4c/source/tools/gennorm2`.

I'm currently getting stuck when running `bazelisk build //icu4c/source/tools/gennorm2 --verbose_failures --sandbox_debug` with [these errors](https://gist.github.com/echeran/6ba9a1252e1946d1fca3b7df60908788).

They reference functions defined in [`urename.h`](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/master/icu4c/source/common/unicode/urename.h). As I understand it, `urename.h` is also used to rename certain functions by appending a suffix with the version number (`_68`), but I defined a preprocessor constant `U_DISABLE_RENAMING` to disable that specific behavior. This only had the effect of changing the names of the undefined function names in the error output, but otherwise not changing it (ex: errors now complain of `u_errorName` instead of `u_errorName_68`).

The part that puzzles me is why the error output claims that these symbols are not found. As you can see, the target `//icu4c/source/tools/gennorm2` depends on `//icu4c/source/common:platform`, which in turn depends on `//icu4c/source/common:headers`, which includes the field `hdrs = glob(["unicode/*.h", "unicode/*.h",])`, which should be matching
`/icu4c/source/common/unicode/urename.h`.

In case it helps, this is the [verbose log output](https://gist.github.com/echeran/d132744ab50285aa5fe291e27005b7e3) when running `make VERBOSE=1` using the current autotools-based configure + make build on a fresh checkout of ICU.

Comment: I've only peeked quickly into the tree and change... it only has the dependency on an interface (to compile), but not the implementation (to link against). As of current state, you appear to have `//icu4c/source/tools/gennorm2` also depend on `//icu4c/source/i18n:icu4ci18n` where `ucal.o` that appears to provide the symbols would be built and included.

Comment: One more comment, really not familiar with that tree, but having a second look. Yes, `ucal.o` does provide those symbols, nonetheless with the `_68` suffix... use of that needs to be consistent across provider and consumer.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Good catch on the dependencies. I showed this to a teammate, who helped me understand the documentation on [the code dependency structure](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/a84fdd0e903fb20acd93ed186a0da4c0c071a0e6/icu4c/source/test/depstest/dependencies.txt). It looks like the errors were ultimately a probably of mis-specifying dependencies that had the effect of not including all the dep code needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A teammate was able to take a look and help me reason through the errors and ultimately fix them.

The first thing is to acknowledge that it is indeed a linker error, which can see by noticing the [error message references the linker program `ld`](https://gist.github.com/echeran/6ba9a1252e1946d1fca3b7df60908788#file-gistfile1-txt-L98).

This is important because we previously spent time in the wrong place by debugging the compile configs as if the problem happened during the compile phase before the linker phase. (But I learned about one way to debug compile problems is taking the raw GCC command given by `--verbose_failures --sandbox_debug` and replacing `-c` with `-E` and changing the argument of `-o` to a .txt file in /tmp to save the output what the compiler sees for that file after all the includes are recursively inlined). This means that my attempts to solve the problem by specifying preprocessor defines for the compile-phase were misguided.

The [project's documentation on dependencies](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/a84fdd0e903fb20acd93ed186a0da4c0c071a0e6/icu4c/source/test/depstest/dependencies.txt) revealed that I had mis-specified a dependency on one of the targets to specify only the headers (`//icu4c/source/common:headers`) instead of the relevant definitions and headers (`//icu4c/source/common:platform`).

After doing that, we solved another problem that was small and interesting. The `gennorm2` target depends on code to get the current year (ex: for printing out help messages that include the copyright statement with the year range). As an i18n library, ICU has code to get that, somewhere in `//icu4c/source/i18n:icu4ci18n`. This creates an excessive amount of code dependencies for an isolated use case (and will cause problems for follow-on work), so we replaced the block of code in `gennorm2` calling those calendar year fns (`ucal_open`, `ucal_getNow`, `ucal_setMillis`, `ucal_get`, `ucal_close`) with the libc date library function to give us the year as a number, and added `linkopts = ["-ldl"]` to link in the `dl` date library.